# Premium tax credit repayment - below poverty line

Tags: united-states, taxes, health-insurance, healthcare, health-reimbursement-arrangement

So when we where signing up for 2018 healthcare. We estimated we would make enough money to qualify for the APTC...and not to much to not qualify for it..In Colorado in 2018 you had to make above a certain amount and below a certain amount to qualify.. so we used the tax credit all year long.. now it's 2020 and im looking at doing my 2018 taxs.. and well we did not make enough money to qualify for the 2018 APTC.. and we used it.. like ALOT of it.

If I file my 2018 taxs now.. I mean I dont even have the 1095-a.. but are they going to say I owe them like $20k ?? haha me having 20k.. thats funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just doing 2018 now? Where have you been? And how could you manage to miss the 1095-A? I got two paper copies by mail (several weeks apart) plus about a dozen emails, all of them marked IMPORTANT in all-caps, sometimes more than once!

The theory of the lower bound of 100% FPL for PTC and APTC (and cost-sharing reduction) was that Medicaid, with expansion if necessary, or SCHIP where applicable, should cover below that, although I don't know whether that worked for Colorado specifically. You were supposed to go back and notify the 'marketplace' when you realized your income would be different than estimated, and they would have automatically enrolled you in Medicaid if possible; obviously it's too late for that now. (BTW the *ratios* of 100% FPL and 400% FPL are the same everywhere; the FPL *amount* varies by year and household size, and also differs for Alaska and Hawaii but is the same for all other states, plus DC).

Anyway, if you 'received' excess APTC (that is, it was paid on your behalf to the insurer) -- and if you didn't qualify, then all of it was excess -- **the amount you are required to repay depends on your MAGI-as-percent-of-FPL**; see the [form 8962 instructions at line 28](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8962#idm140224345762208). (Note only the most recent year is browsable and thus linkable on the website, so that is the 2019 version; the [prior-year versions are available in PDF](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/prior-year) -- but this item didn't change.) **Since you were under 100% FPL that limit is $300 if single or $600 otherwise.**

Comment: Thank you for your concise answer I know you mean the best but the first paragraph is unnecessary as I hate myself enough already and do not need someone else telling me i'm horrible; I do it enough to myself already.

You see some people suffer from severe depression. Disabling depression that everyone thinks is a lie or an excuse to be lazy. These people avoid things that make them feel worse..like taxes and money.. with the express purpose of not committing suicide.

Wild world we live in.